# What is the best way to count time durations in CSV file?

Tags: python, datetime, csv, row

I have  following kind of data in CSV file:

```
1; 28.11.2014 3:2:43; 
0; 28.11.2014 3:3:58; 
1; 28.11.2014 5:31:36; 
0; 28.11.2014 5:33:7; 
2; 28.11.2014 7:10:40; 
0; 28.11.2014 9:50:10; 
...
```

What I am trying to do is count how long each status flag is up and then sum these amounts. In example; flag 1 is up 75 seconds (row 1), etc.. Would it be most effective to count all times between rows at first (place then somewhere) and then sum up times or somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import csv

totalTime = datetime.timedelta(0)

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=';')
    for start, end in zip(reader):
        start = start[1]
        end = end[1]
        start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        totalTime += end-start
print("total time flags were up", totalTime.total_seconds())
```